# shell script - interpret code

Tags: php, shell

I'm just a beginner in shell script. I'm reading the code of my co-worker and I don't know what is the meaning of the below code. Can any one help me on what is the meaning of the below code, specially the `RESULT` line.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATETIME=$(date);
LOGFILE="/var/www/ema/services/generate.log";
ENDRESULT="DONE";

RESULT=$(curl -s 127.0.0.1/services/generatereport.php);

if [[ "$RESULT" =~ "$ENDRESULT" ]]; then
    RESULT="Generation Ended";
    echo "["$DATETIME"]"$RESULT >> $LOGFILE;
else
    echo "["$DATETIME"]"$RESULT >> $LOGFILE;
    /var/www/ema/services/generate.sh;  
fi
```

the filename of this script is `generate.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `RESULT=$(curl -s 127.0.0.1/services/generatereport.php);` is using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to load a resource, in this case the file *generatereport.php*. **UPDATE:** It is basically executing the command curl, which requests a file from a server. The option -s is silent mode, to avoid any error messages or progress bar. From the curl documentation:

> **-s, --silent**
>
> Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.

Since the IP address used is 127.0.0.1 (localhost), he is simply executing the file from the folder *services* in localhost. The output of the file is stored in the variable RESULT.

The next if statement `[[ "$RESULT" =~ "$ENDRESULT" ]];`, compares the end of **RESULT** with the value of the variable **ENDRESULT**, which is "DONE", in that case the report generation has finished, and it stores the sentence `"Generation Ended"` in a logfile, as "[Date]*Generation Ended*".

The logfile is located in `/var/www/ema/services/generate.log`

In the second case, it stores the output of `generatereport.php` in the log file as well, although this time it also calls the shell script file located at `/var/www/ema/services/generate.sh`

Comment: thank you for explanation. may I also know what is the meaning of "curl" and "-s" on the RESULT line?

Answer (score 2):

I've commented the code for you :)

```
#!/bin/bash
DATETIME=$(date); // Get current date
LOGFILE="/var/www/ema/services/generate.log"; // Where to save data
ENDRESULT="DONE"; // What to expect at the end of data

RESULT=$(curl -s 127.0.0.1/services/generatereport.php); // Request data from PHP running on localhost

if [[ "$RESULT" =~ "$ENDRESULT" ]]; then // If $RESULT ends with "DONE" then log to file that everything is okay;
    RESULT="Generation Ended";
    echo "["$DATETIME"]"$RESULT >> $LOGFILE;
else // Otherwise write down the error and run some other script.
    echo "["$DATETIME"]"$RESULT >> $LOGFILE; 
    /var/www/ema/services/generate.sh;  
fi
```

Comment: No, if "DONE" response is received it overrites $RESULT with "Generation Ended" and writes that to file.